# Gallary setting for whatsapp

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

If get images or videos from different group in whatsapp its getting stored twice or thrice in gallery .I want it to be stored only once kindly help

Answer (score 2):

You cannot avoid this duplication of photos as all the photos are treated as different files by Android. However, you can use a third party app, like [Clone Buster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lasgafasdemike.clonebuster&hl=en) to remove all duplicate files from time to time.